# Warning: Automatically setting basename using <base href>

Tags: reactjs

Warning

```
Warning: Automatically setting basename using <base href> is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. The semantics of <base href> are subtly different from basename. Please pass the basename explicitly in the options to createHistory
```

Imports

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, IndexRedirect, browserHistory, Redirect} from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
```

History

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
```

Este es mi router

```js
<Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Landing} onEnter={checkToken}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/demos" component={App} onEnter={checkToken}>
          <IndexRoute component={demosList} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/categories" component={App} onEnter={checkToken}>
          <IndexRoute component={Categories} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/users" component={App} onEnter={checkToken}>
          <IndexRoute component={Users} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={login} onEnter={isLoged}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/logout" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={logout} onEnter={isLogedOut}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/reset" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={resetPassword}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
```

Comment: Un warning no es un error

Comment: Lo se, pero quiero eliminar todas las warnings de mi sitio. Ya corregi el post no me di cuenta de que puse Error